# Why isn't this checkbox submitting data? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a Rails app which shows a list of restaurants with different parameters. I'm trying to add a filter through a checkbox so that if user checks the checkbox, the view only shows those posts where the restaurants is Zagat rated.

My code is below. Why isn't it working?

**POSTS INDEX FILE (INDEX.HTML.ERB)**

```
<script type="javascript">
function sendData() {
    $.post( "index",{'zagat_status':$('#zagat_status'.val("")})
    .done(function(data) {
       alert('Success!');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#zagat_status').change(function() {
         sendData();
    });
});
</script>
            <label>  Zagat<dd>rated</dd><input type="checkbox" name="zagat_status" value="Yes">
            </label>
```

**POSTS CONTROLLER**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    if params[:search]
      @posts = @posts.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    if params[:zagat_status].present?
      @posts = @posts.zagat_status(params[:zagat_status]).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
```

**POSTS MODEL**

```
  scope :zagat_status, -> (zagat_status) { where zagat_status: zagat_status }
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working ? (For example, is the Ajax call made or not? Does your controller receive the correct params or not?). Also, your checkbox doesn't have id zagat_status, which the rest of your code seems to assume.

Comment: i tried adding id of zagat_status, still doesn't work. when i look in my rails log, i don't see anything that confirms the box was checked. how do i check if the ajax call is being made or not?

Comment: Chrome has a network inspector tab

Comment: Ok, i looked there, i only see one network call being made, to a Google maps API (which is part of my app). Not sure if that's helpful/ what you were looking for?

Comment: also: i checked my development log. it shows no sign that the data is being submitted. literally nothing changes in my development log when i check/uncheck the box –

Comment: Then check for JavaScript errors in the browser console, sprinkle some breakpoints in your js etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting the right value for the checkbox?  If you put the line

`raise params.to_s` at the start of your index function, is it sending the params you want?  That would help determine if the issue is on the javascript side (most likely) or on the rails server side.

I recently ran into a similar issue where calling 
`$('#zagat_status').val()`

did not give me the value I want.  Try using the snippet below, where you call `($(this).is(':checked'))` to see if the checkbox is checked and pass it to your controller.

```
$('#zagat_status').change(function(){
    var isChecked = ($(this).is(':checked'))
     $.post( "index",{'zagat_status': isChecked })
.done(function(data) {
   alert('Success!');
});
})
```

Comment: i replaced all of my javascript code in the index.html.erb file with your code above, put it in a script tag, and tried again, but did not work.

Comment: also i checked my development log. it shows no sign that the data is being submitted. literally nothing changes in my development log when i check/uncheck the box

Comment: One thing I just noticed - you are using zagat_status as name for your input, but identifying it as '#zagat_status' in jquery.  Give your checkbox the id='zagat_status'  as well so that the id catches it, or change your jquery selector to be selecting by name attribute.

The fact that the development log doesn't change when you click/unclick means jquery isn't registering the click action.